How to connect a dockerized django application to a non dockerized postgres database?
I have a dockerized django application and It works fine to connect it to a dockerized postgres database. I would like to modify the settings.py to connect to a local database in my machine or in the network but I just do not know how to map it. shall I use a network. there is not documentation for this.
In fact the policy of my company is not to dockerize databases, but we are encouraged to dockerize applications.
please help.
I used the following dockerfile.
# Start with the official Python image
FROM python:3.11
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /home/app
# Preventing python from writing
# pyc to docker container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Flushing out python buffer
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt .
#RUN ..\bin\activate.
RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
# Copy project files
COPY . .
# Expose the localhost port  on docker image on the port below. This is not used for mapping it but to expose it for comunication.
EXPOSE 8000
# Run the Django server . we will run django on port 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "127.0.0.1:8000"]
###############settings.py########################
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'devsearch',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',

    }
}


The linked question describes how to connect to a non-container database on the same system.  If the database is on a different host, you shouldn't have to do anything special, use the same configuration you'd use locally; you do not need to manually create or configure Docker networks.
